# All WordPress AJAX calls always return 0

Tags: ajax

After page migration I have a problem with all AJAX calls. They always returning 0. I probably done everything and can't figure out what is wrong? Could you help me please?

Ajax call as shorten form:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type : 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data : {
        action : 'ajax_newsletter',
        email : 'aaa@aaa.aaa'
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Functions.php function as shorten form:

```
function ajax_newsletter() {
    $response = [];
    $resposne['succcess'] = true;
    wp_send_json($response);
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_newsletter', 'ajax_newsletter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_newsletter', 'ajax_newsletter');
```

Comment: First of all, you have a typo in your php function - you set 'resposne' value and not 'response'

Comment: That is true. I changed logic of function just for that question. Fix of typo nothing changed. Still 0 for all requests. Old server has no problem with ajax calls.

Comment: And is your site located in root directory of that domain? You pass `url` in a very risky way...

Comment: In original version I have url as typical wp variable url: ajaxurl. I always get the response from server with status code 200.

Comment: I have got solution... The problem was empty file /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php after copying from server to server...